# JS: how to get current datetime?

Tags: javascript, datetime

simple problem:

When I try this on console:

```
new Date('2018', '01', '08')
```

I get this output

```
Date 2018-02-07T13:00:00.000Z
```

How to get it to the date I just set? like `2018-01-08T00:00:00`?

Thanks a lot

Comment: As mentioned in Christian's answer, month is zero-based. Other than that, it actually is showing the date that you requested, it's just showing it in UTC time. For more information on the Javascript date object, I recommend this excellent post in an older question https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/3415209

Comment: I see the post, but I cant convert into a specific timezone.. it has to be the user visiting. so it should just show output the system time

Comment: @RaheelHasan try using moment.js for your datetime object. It is an excellent library for such kind of manipulations

Comment: @RasheelHasan I understand, I was just trying to point you in the direction of some background on how the Date object works. I'm guessing you're in a timezone similar to Sydney, Australia - +11 UTC. `2018-01-07T13:00:00.000Z` is exactly the same as `2018-01-08T00:00:00.000` in the UTC+11 timezone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `month` parameter in the `Date` constructor is 0-based, meaning the months start from 0, not 1.

To get January as your date, you need to set month to 0:

```
new Date('2018', '0', '08')
```

For UTC, you can use `Date.UTC` to specify that the year, month and day are in UTC:

```
new Date(Date.UTC("2018", "0", "1"))
```

Comment: new Date('2018', '0', '08') = 
`Date 2018-01-07T13:00:00.000Z`

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the answer above by `Christian`, you can do the following to get `current` local time:

```
new Date(new Date()+'utc');
```